# C++ Socks5 communication Issues

Tags: c++, visual-c++, networking, socks, tor

I am still trying to make a connection to a Server through a SOCKS5 Proxy. I have read the RFC1928 and now I am using this code, but it doesn't work as expected.
There seems to be a Problem with sending the domain name. When changing addr bit to 1 and using IP address it works just fine.

The code I use is this:

```
#define PUT_BYTE(ptr,data) (*(unsigned char*)ptr = data)
struct sockaddr_in saddr;
saddr.sin_port = htons(9150);
saddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
saddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
int rv = connect(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&saddr, sizeof(saddr));
if (rv < SOCKET_ERROR)
    return 1;

char buf[256], *ptr;
ptr = buf;
PUT_BYTE(ptr++, 5); // Version 5
PUT_BYTE(ptr++, 1);
PUT_BYTE(ptr++, 0x00); // No Auth
send(fd, buf, ptr - buf, 0);
recv(fd, buf, 2, 0);
if ((buf[0] != 5) || buf[1] == 0xFF)
{
    exit(0);
}
ptr = buf;
PUT_BYTE(ptr++, 5); // Version 5
PUT_BYTE(ptr++, 1); // Connect
PUT_BYTE(ptr++, 0); // Reserved
PUT_BYTE(ptr++, 3); // Use Hostname
//memcpy(ptr, &destaddr.sin_addr.s_addr, sizeof(destaddr.sin_addr));
//ptr += sizeof(destaddr.sin_addr);
//PUT_BYTE(ptr++, static_cast<unsigned char>(21));
PUT_BYTE(ptr++, 22); // Set Hostname lenght
//ptr += static_cast<unsigned char>(22);
//ptr += static_cast<unsigned char>(address.c_str());
//memcpy(ptr, &"iszgnywrejvdg2nc.onion", sizeof("iszgnywrejvdg2nc.onion") + 4);
PUT_BYTE(ptr++, (byte)"iszgnywrejvdg2nc.onion"); // set Hostname
PUT_BYTE(ptr++, 0xFF); //Set Hostname end
PUT_BYTE(ptr++, dest_port >> 8); //set port
PUT_BYTE(ptr++, dest_port & 0xFF); //set port end
send(fd, buf, ptr - buf, 0); //send out data
recv(fd, buf, 4, 0); // read response
if (!buf[1] != 0x00) // check response
{
    ptr = buf + 4;
    switch (buf[3]) {
    case 1:
        recv(fd, ptr, 4 + 2, 0);
        break;
    case 3:
        recv(fd, ptr, 1, 0);
        recv(fd, ptr + 1, *(unsigned char*)ptr + 2, 0);
        break;
    case 4:
        recv(fd, ptr, 16 + 2, 0);
        break;
    }
}
```

This is the RFC which should match the above

```
    +----+-----+-------+------+----------+----------+
    |VER | CMD |  RSV  | ATYP | DST.ADDR | DST.PORT |
    +----+-----+-------+------+----------+----------+
    | 1  |  1  | X'00' |  1   | Variable |    2     |
    +----+-----+-------+------+----------+----------+

 Where:

      o  VER    protocol version: X'05'
      o  CMD
         o  CONNECT X'01'
         o  BIND X'02'
         o  UDP ASSOCIATE X'03'
      o  RSV    RESERVED
      o  ATYP   address type of following address
         o  IP V4 address: X'01'
         o  DOMAINNAME: X'03'
         o  IP V6 address: X'04'
      o  DST.ADDR       desired destination address
      o  DST.PORT desired destination port in network octet
         order
```

Comment: Can you please comment you code a bit? We shouldn't have to look up doc reference guides to follow your code.

Comment: @S.Richmond I have commented and Included the according RFC

Comment: I would suggest that you use something like Wireshark to review the packets you're creating and sending to make sure they're properly constructed.

Comment: @S.Richmond Wireshark displays this 05 01 00 03 16 34 ff 4b fc as the second send request. All after the 16 is unexpected. Can someone explain what is happening there??

Answer (score 0):

Your code that is populating the `dst.addr` field with a hostname is completely wrong.  In particular, on this line:

```
PUT_BYTE(ptr++, (byte)"iszgnywrejvdg2nc.onion"); // set Hostname
```

You are type-casting a `char*` pointer to a single byte.  You are storing the last byte of a truncated pointer value, you are not copying the hostname data into the field at all.  You should be using `memcpy()` or `strcpy()` instead, similar to what you are doing in your commented code (but which has errors, too).

Also, this line does not belong at all and needs to be removed:

```
PUT_BYTE(ptr++, 0xFF); //Set Hostname end
```

Try something more like this instead:

```
char buf[263], *ptr;
...
ptr = buf;
PUT_BYTE(ptr++, 5); // Version 5
PUT_BYTE(ptr++, 1); // Connect
PUT_BYTE(ptr++, 0); // Reserved
PUT_BYTE(ptr++, 3); // Use Hostname
char *hostname = "iszgnywrejvdg2nc.onion";
unsigned char len = (unsigned char) strlen(hostname);
PUT_BYTE(ptr++, len); // Set Hostname length
memcpy(ptr, hostname, len); // set Hostname
ptr += len;
PUT_BYTE(ptr++, dest_port >> 8); //set port
PUT_BYTE(ptr++, dest_port & 0xFF); //set port end
```